# what's the right choice talking about specific time of the day, at or in?

Tags: prepositions, expressions, time

I believe At is used for : specific time and Holiday period
and IN is used for: months, years,Decades, century,season and time period.
But when I try google translator with both options:

At night....at the evening?
in the evening?

It seems has the same meaning I don't know which is the right choice.

Answer (score 1):

The original poster's general rule is correct:

- "at" or "on" is used for events (such as points in time or days)
- "in" or "during" is used for time ranges (such as months, years, or decades)

The original poster correctly noticed an exception.  We say:

- "in the evening" or "on the evening of"
- "at" or "on" a special day's "Eve", to refer to the day before the special day.  For example, "Halloween" is "All Hallows' Eve", and "New Year's Eve" is the day before "New Year's Day".
- "at night" or "on the night of"
- "by day" or "on the day of"

Comment: thanks a lot for your help, I will memorize the exception!, but I'm still confused , in which way is correct, In the evening?, at the evening?

Comment: @HoneyObando -- "In the evening" is correct.  "At the evening" is only correct when "evening" is an attributive noun, such as in "You can see us at the evening show."